# React Native - unit test fails because of Native Module

Tags: java, typescript, react-native, ts-jest

I am getting a weird anomaly when I declare a [Native Java Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) the new code doesn't pass unit test. Basically whatever I import from `NativeModules` in React Native lacks a definition: So the Unit test fails because `TypeError: Cannot read property 'HelloWorld' of undefined`

Steps to reproduce:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const Thing = NativeModules.SomeModule;

export const helloWorld = (addedText: string) => {
  return Thing.HelloWorld(addedText);
};

export default Thing;
```

but the error is

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'HelloWorld' of undefined

  4 |
  5 | export const helloWorld = (addedText: string) => {
> 6 |   return Thing.HelloWorld(addedText);
    |                ^
  7 | };
  8 |
  9 | export default Thing;
```

the actual  Java is

```
public class SomeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule  {

  SomeModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
  }
  
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "SomeModule";
  }
  void HelloWorld(String addedText){
     try {
       Log.w("HELLO_WORLD", addedText);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("DEVICE_MODULE_HELLO_WORLD_FAILED", "HelloWorld() Failed");
     }
  }
}
```

and this *runs* fine (when you run it) but the unit tests hate it. The issue seems to be that the React Native test lacks an awareness of the structure of `const helloWorld = (addedText: string) => {  return Thing.HelloWorld(addedText); };` so I dutifully [made this `d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) to help

```
declare namespace Thing {
   function helloWorld(addedText: string): void;
}
```

but it still fails when at unit test, it feels wrong for me to simply assume this has been overlooked, so I am assuming I must have implemented something incorrectly. Can anyone shed light on the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is to mock out the function

in the test file, (the test to whatever part of your code in react-native *calls* `helloWorld("bob chips")`) (i.e *not* where it exports) you have to mock out the Java module as follows. Note this is global (once) at the top of the file that launched the failed test - perhaps you put `helloWorld("bob chips")` in `Place.tsx` if so perhaps the `Place.test.tsx` fails - because it references `helloWorld("bob chips")`, if so in the one that has tests that fail - inside `Place.test.tsx` - do this *once* at the top of the file:

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  const RN = jest.requireActual('react-native');
  RN.NativeModules.SomeModule = {
    HelloWorld: jest.fn(),
  };

  // mock modules created through UIManager
  RN.UIManager.getViewManagerConfig = (name) => {
    if (name === 'SomeModule') {
      return { HelloWorld: jest.fn() };
    }
    return {};
  };
  return RN;
});
```

this then `suppresses` jest trying to test it, and allows you to write tests in `java` to compensate